# selecting items from database and displaying it into a web page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, oracle11g

first i am using isp, servlets, oracle SQL developer, eclipse  ... and i have a table called MEMBERS which have id, fname, lname, age, weight, height, sex and on my jsp i have a combobox which has sex(female/male), age(from 1 to 100) and "GO" button and i want to select certain sex and age and then when i hit the button all members having this certain sex and age will be displayed in a table ..
i am new to java so i need your help .. thanks

Comment: You might need to first take a tutorial by searching on google?

Comment: i already did but still cant make it

Comment: Take much smaller steps. Start with one single field, make that work correctly (including validation). Then add a checkbox, make that work. Then other another field, etc. Don't try and do it all at once.